# Can not find installed packages in GitHub actions

Tags: python, github, github-actions

```
name: MyAction
on:
  workflow_dispatch
jobs:
  'myjob':
    runs_on: [self-hosted, linux]
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python Virt Env
      run: python -m venv venv
    - name: Install deps
      run: |
        source venv/bin/activate
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        cd mydir
        pip install -r requirements.txt
        pip install -e .
    - name: Do commands
      run: |
        source venv/bin/activate
        cd mydir
        mybinary
```

mybinary is a file which lies in venv/bin, but it can not be found.

I checked PATH and it contains venv/bin , that's why I tried to use rehash, but no success. The most interesting that if I login to than node and try to use mybinary, I will see it with ls command, but can not use. When I try to execute it, it appears “no such file”. Even if I use full path.

Comment: `rehash` is not a built-in command in Bash or standard Bourne-shell variants (like `dash`).

Comment: I checked shell there. It is tcsh.
Also I tried "which rehash" manually on machine and it said that it is builtin command.

Comment: But your commands aren't running under `tcsh`. They're running with `/bin/sh`. See the [documentation for the `run` directive](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun) to see how to use a specific shell (or just learn how to use standard shell syntax instead of relying on `tcsh`).

Comment: thanks. But why can't I find mybinary? It is in venv/bin, I checked manually and PATH is correct

Comment: Ah, I had not noticed that you are using a self-hosted runner. Maybe that changes things? The fact that you're getting the `command not found` error suggests that I am correct in any case; try one of the solutions I've suggested and see if that resolves the error.

Comment: No, I checked. I still can not find anything. Even if I login to node. I can see all the files, but when I try to use it, it is thrown “no such file”

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved.
mybinary file has very long shebang on the first line. It was created during installation of Python package from virtual environment. According to limits of Linux this shebang is cut on 80 symbols, and exactly this cut path can not be found.